# unix join, trying to do an outer join

Tags: bash, unix, join, outer-join

I am trying to outer join 2 csv files but for some reason the code is joining only the first line and not the whole file.

csv1.csv:

[image]

csv2.csv:

[image]

As shown they have some common fields and some that are not. So I would like to outer join these 2 files. I am fine with having blank values for values that don't exist.
I tried this http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/01/join-command.html for help but the code doesn't seem to be working for me.

for example:
[image]

I am not sure why it is only joining the first row. I tried:
join -t"," -1 1 csv1.csv csv2.csv
and got the same result. and -a1 or -a2 returns the whole csv file except the first row. I don't quite understand why they are unmatched. 
Can anyone help?

I spent a couple hours on this and seems like I am not making much progress.

Thanks in advance

If I do join -t"," -1 1 -a1 -a2 csv1.csv csv2.csv

I get the joined header followed by csv2 + nonexisting fields at csv1 added.

I am really confused.

Comment: please add the contents of the csv files to the question, not images. That will make it easier for people trying to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a database if you want to utilize database operations.

```
#!/bin/bash

sqlite3 ./temp.db <<EOF | sort >joined.csv
CREATE TABLE a (name varchar(50), port1 real, port2 real, avg real);
CREATE TABLE b (name varchar(50), port1 real, port2 real, avg real);
.mode csv
.import csv1.csv a
.import csv2.csv b
SELECT a.name,a.port1,a.port2,a.avg,b.port1,b.port2,b.avg
FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.name = b.name
UNION
SELECT b.name,a.port1,a.port2,a.avg,b.port1,b.port2,b.avg
FROM b LEFT OUTER JOIN a ON b.name = a.name;
EOF

rm ./temp.db
```

Comment: I have never used sqlite3 before. Can you eloborate how I can access this newly created table. Looking at the sql commands this looks like exactly what I wish to do tho.

Comment: aha I see the csv. For some reason the order is changed tho. I think alphabetically. other than that looks right I guess.

Comment: You don't need to access anything. The script creates a temporary database with 2 tables, reads the 2 CSV files into the tables, joins the tables and writes the result to `joined.csv`. The temporary database is deleted thereafter. As for the ordering: I had to sort the output, because SQLite doesn't support FULL OUTER JOINs and the UNION of the two LEFT OUTER JOINs printed the header line last.

Comment: I was wondering what if I have like 30 of these files. Do I need to join them one by one or is there a way to loop and join all the tables I place in the database.

Comment: Then you better use a database that supports FULL OUTER JOINs. ;)